# Entity framework calculated field by Expression<Func<T,V>>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I would like to create calculated fields only in .net code, without defining columns in sql.

For example in this classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }            
    public string FirstName { get; set; }            
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }            
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }    
    public static Expression<Func<Customer, int>> CustomerBirthYear_Exp = a => a.BirthDate.Year;    
    /// Populated by CustomerBirthYear_Exp
    public int CustomerBirthYear { get; private set; }            
    public static Expression<Func<Customer, string>> CustomerLastName_Exp = a => a.LastName + " " + a.FirstName;    
    /// Populated by CustomerLastName_Exp
    public string CustomerFullName { get; private set; }
}
```

when I query for Order (ctx.Orders.Select(...)...), Customer table should be joined and CustomerBirthYear and CustomerFullName should be populated. Equivalent to

```
        from o in ctx.Orders
        join a in ctx.Customers on o.CustomerId equals  a.Id
        select new
                {
                    o.Id,
                    CustomerFullName = a.LastName + " " + a.FirstName,
                    CustomerBirthYear_Exp = a.BirthDate.Year
                };
```

Is there any way to achive this by defining custom expression for specific member?
In one other ORM there are way to declare this:
 Register(System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression substitution)
Registers substitution as a substitution for member.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not currently possible. The closest I've seen is using [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to build reusable "selectors" that are too lengthy/common to want to repeat in code. It ends up looking like:

```
var fullNameSelector = MyExpressions.FullNameSelector;
var query = from o in ctx.Orders.AsExpandable()
            select new
            {
                Id = o.Id,
                FullName = fullNameSelector.Invoke(o)
            };
```